# Starting a shape animation from VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to trigger a shape animation from VBA code?

pom

Answer (score 4):

Pom,

In any version less than powerpoint 2010, no it does not appear possible: http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/vba_Triggers.html.

However, if you are using powerpoint 2010, MSDN details a [straightforward demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg190747.aspx) for triggering shape animations in powerpoint:

```
Sub TestShapeAnimation()

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        Dim shp1, shp2, shp3 As Shape
        ' This sets the initial shape, with which we will test the animation sequences.
        Set shp1 = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShape12pointStar, 20, 20, 100, 100)

        ' This creates the animations.
        .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect shp1, msoAnimEffectFadedSwivel, , msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious
        .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect shp1, msoAnimEffectPathBounceRight, , msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious
        .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect shp1, msoAnimEffectSpin, , msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious

        ' This acquires the animation... [i]
        shp1.PickupAnimation

        ' [i] ... and applies it to another shape.
        Set shp2 = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeHexagon, 100, 20, 100, 100)
        shp2.ApplyAnimation

        ' Another shape creation / animation application.
        Set shp3 = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCloud, 180, 20, 100, 100)
        shp3.ApplyAnimation

    End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if you have further questions/thoughts -

~JOL

Answer (score 2):

JackOrangeLantern's response is unfortunately not especially responsive to the original question.
JOL's response will help you copy animations on the timeline and apply them to different shapes, but it will not actually trigger them.

If you have Powerpoint 2010 or earlier, there is no direct way to actually trigger an animation with VBA. I am not very familiar with the newer versions of Powerpoint, but I don't think they have this feature either.

Actually triggering interactive animations seems to require an actual mouse click which can not be easily simulated in Powerpoint without some advanced and overly complicated coding that might involve actually messing with the Windows API. The best workaround I have found for this is to not send mouse clicks to the shapes on the slide but to instead send keyboard strokes.

I discovered this solution from PPT Alchemy [Mouseover trigger an animation with vba code](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/vba_Triggers.html)

```
Sub anim()
   SendKeys("{TAB}")
   SendKeys("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```

This code will activate the first interactive Trigger On the slide. To activate the second Trigger animation on the slide you would send the {TAB} key twice instead of once. This is definately the easiest way to activate trigger animations on a powerpoint slide. It is a shame there isn't a better way.

Follow the link for a more thorough explanation.
Take care. :)